# android mediaplayer over 3g connection not work but work on wifi

Tags: android, connection, media-player, wifi, 3g

I am working on a project that uses videoView to display a .mp4 video from url. My code works in the emulator fine but on the physical device (Samsung siii) it only works over WiFi and  not work over 3G.

Comment: Do you have an IP connection over the 3G network?  How strong is the network?  What is the network technology (GPRS, UMTS, HSPA etc)?

Answer (score 0):

youtube video works fine over 3g and and i test same video with other player vplayer and itz wrok fine..

this is my code

package com.video;

public class StreamingVideoPlayer extends Activity implements
        OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener, OnInfoListener,
        OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnPreparedListener, OnSeekCompleteListener,
        OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {

```
MediaController controller;
Display currentDisplay;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

View mainView;
TextView statusView;

int videoWidth = 0;
int videoHeight = 0;

boolean readyToPlay = false;
public final static String LOGTAG = "STREAMING_VIDEO_PLAYER";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mainView = this.findViewById(R.id.MainView);

    statusView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.StatusTextView);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer Created");

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);




    //String filePath = "http://sffsapps.s3.amazonaws.com/02-benefits-100dc.mp4";

//  String filePath="http://100dcapps.s3.amazonaws.com/droidtest/index.droid.mp4"; 

String filePath="https://100dcapps.s3.amazonaws.com/droidtest/index.mp4";

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }

    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer DataSource Set");
    currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    controller = new MediaController(this);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "surfaceCreated Called");

    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer Display Surface Set");

    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "IllegalStateException " + e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }

    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer Preparing");
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "surfaceChanged Called");
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "surfaceDestroyed Called");
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onCompletion Called");
    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer Playback Completed");
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int whatError, int extra) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onError Called");
    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer Error");
    if (whatError == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Error, Server Died " + extra);
    } else if (whatError == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Error, Error Unknown " + extra);
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int whatInfo, int extra) {
    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer onInfo Called");
    if (whatInfo == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BAD_INTERLEAVING) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Info, Media Info Bad Interleaving " + extra);
    } else if (whatInfo == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_NOT_SEEKABLE) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Info, Media Info Not Seekable " + extra);
    } else if (whatInfo == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_UNKNOWN) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Info, Media Info Unknown " + extra);
    } else if (whatInfo == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_TRACK_LAGGING) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "MediaInfo, Media Info Video Track Lagging " + extra);
    } /*
     * Android version 2.0 or higher else if (whatInfo ==
     * MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_METADATA_UPDATE) { Log.v(LOGTAG,
     * "MediaInfo, Media Info Metadata Update " + extra); }
     */
    return false;
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onPrepared Called");
    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer Prepared");

    videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
    videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

    Log.v(LOGTAG, "Width: " + videoWidth);
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "Height: " + videoHeight);

    if (videoWidth > currentDisplay.getWidth()
            || videoHeight > currentDisplay.getHeight()) {
        float heightRatio = (float) videoHeight
                / (float) currentDisplay.getHeight();
        float widthRatio = (float) videoWidth
                / (float) currentDisplay.getWidth();

        if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1) {
            if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
                videoHeight = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoHeight
                        / (float) heightRatio);
                videoWidth = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoWidth
                        / (float) heightRatio);
            } else {
                videoHeight = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoHeight
                        / (float) widthRatio);
                videoWidth = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoWidth
                        / (float) widthRatio);
            }
        }
    }

    surfaceView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(videoWidth,
            videoHeight));
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView(this.findViewById(R.id.MainView));
    controller.setEnabled(true);
    controller.show();

    mp.start();
    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer Started");
}

public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onSeekComplete Called");
}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onVideoSizeChanged Called");

    videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
    videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

    Log.v(LOGTAG, "Width: " + videoWidth);
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "Height: " + videoHeight);

    if (videoWidth > currentDisplay.getWidth()
            || videoHeight > currentDisplay.getHeight()) {
        float heightRatio = (float) videoHeight
                / (float) currentDisplay.getHeight();
        float widthRatio = (float) videoWidth
                / (float) currentDisplay.getWidth();

        if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1) {
            if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
                videoHeight = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoHeight
                        / (float) heightRatio);
                videoWidth = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoWidth
                        / (float) heightRatio);
            } else {
                videoHeight = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoHeight
                        / (float) widthRatio);
                videoWidth = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoWidth
                        / (float) widthRatio);
            }
        }
    }

    surfaceView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(videoWidth,
            videoHeight));
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int bufferedPercent) {
    statusView.setText("MediaPlayer Buffering: " + bufferedPercent + "%");
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "MediaPlayer Buffering: " + bufferedPercent + "%");
}

public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public void pause() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

public void seekTo(int pos) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
}

public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    /*if (controller.isShowing()) {
        controller.hide();
    } else {*/
        controller.show();
    //}
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: is this the answer or the extended question?